# is this a DateTime bug in php code ? 7.0.0

Tags: php, datetime

This is the idea:

```
<?php
    $postESDate = 0;

    $sDate = $postESDate;
    $esDate = $sDate + 25;  


    echo $sDate.' ------- ';
    echo $esDate;
?>
```

1. Start with 1 variable, make a new variable that is whatever the 1st var is.
2. Make a second var that is whatever the 2nd var is plus 25.
3. When you echo the 2nd and 3rd var they are different, right?

   This is not the same when modifying dates, try this code below...

   ```
   //fails
   $postESDate = '2017-04-15';

   $sDate = new DateTime($postESDate);

   $esDate = $sDate->modify('+25 days')->format('l jS F Y');   
   $sDate = $sDate->format('l jS F Y');    


   echo $sDate.' ------- ';
   echo $esDate;
   ```

This echos both dates as the same. The problem is it is actually updating the $sDate with the +25 days rather than just saving the output to $esDate as I have requested so therefore the 2nd date format is now +25 days too.. the same.

The fix is this to make another DateTime variable:

```
//works

$postESDate = '2017-04-15';

$sDate = new DateTime($postESDate);
$esDate = new DateTime($postESDate);

$esDate = $esDate->modify('+25 days')->format('l jS F Y');
$sDate = $sDate->format('l jS F Y');    


echo $sDate.' ------- '
echo $esDate;
```

This shouldn't be happening right, or am I missing something ? Well at least i have a work around.

Comment: `DateTimeImmutable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) you'll see that this is the expected behavior. `modify` alters the timestamp of the object you called `modify` on, then returns it for method chaining - which is exactly what you did there.

Comment: i see, thanks Peter, it looks like u_mulders suggestion is great for this :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a common behavior when it comes to objects.
Variables behave like you mentioned, each variable are their own, yes, but objects behave differently.

You can see the same behavior here, for example:

```
$test = new stdClass();
$test->sample = "What!?";

$another = $test;
$another->sample = "Impossibru!";

echo $another->sample . "<br>";
echo $test->sample . "<br>";
```

Unless you clone this object or create a new instance of it, they will be passed by reference.